# How can I modify my KDE environment without restarting?

Tags: environment-variables, kde-4

I am running KDE 4.10. I have added an environment variable to my .profile, however this variable will obviously not be visible to programs that I start via the KDE GUI (as opposed to a shell with the updated environment) until I restart KDE.

Is there a way to tell KDE to re-read the environment, or to explicitly set the KDE environment via DBUS or similar mechanism?

One hack is to restart KDE programs like klauncher and krunner from a shell having the modified environment, but I'm looking for something more elegant (elegant means not having to alter the memory of running programs via `gdb`, haha).

Have we finally found something Windows can do easily that KDE/Linux cannot?

**Update 04/18**: Updated to KDE 4.10, added comment about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

All of my efforts to do the same have been for naught... Environment variables are special things, a child cannot change the parent's environment, while a parent process can adjust things prior to forking a child.

Like you mentioned, you CAN start the needed programs from a newly started konsole, which would have inherited the new .profile settings, but for some that just isn't enough.

Alas... you'll need to log out and then back in again, as a minimum.  So sorry.  But look at the bright side... you don't have to reboot.

(Hmmm, start another new X-server on :1 (or :2, etc), adjust the DISPLAY env-vars of all the programs you need to keep running, to shift them to the new X server.. then kill the first server and switch to the new one.  (mind you, this is somewhat easier to SAY, than DO) )

---

EDIT:
I had another IDEA!!    If you were to use [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb) to break into the *kwin* process, using specially crafted function calls, you COULD add any number of environment variables, change values, whatever.... which would then be reflected in any new programs/processes you started from that point on.   I've done it to change a processes 'current directory' to umount/remount things.  Probably not for the faint of heart... But that's not what we cater to here is it?  HeeHee!  It's possible!  I suppose you could also just break into every process you have running, inject the new environment variable values.  Then you wouldn't have to restart anything.

Wise words from *Uncle Ben* (Spiderman, not the RICE! sheesh!).... "*With great power, comes great responsibility*" Methinks I'll just put that Idea Card in the "As Yet Unproven" stack for now.  YOU do it first... I'll watch... from over here... behind this blast door...